# How to save computational time by using built-in functions and avoid looping over for loops for large numpy arrays in python?

Tags: python, arrays, math, numpy, scipy

I have two numpy arrays of shape (21,3) and (10^6,3). I want to do some mathematical calculations on them (like find out distances). To do so, I use the following code. However it is cumbersome and slow.

The format of data in both the numpy arrays are:

```
[ [x1,y1,z1], [x2,y2,z2], [x3,y3,z3] ]
```

Here is the code:

```
sum_inv_dist = 0.0
sum_inv_dist_array = []
n = 0
for point in sph_rand_pos_u:
    for gal in gal_pos:
        x = gal[0]
        y = gal[1]
        z = gal[2]
        dx = x - point[0]
        dy = y - point[1]
        dz = z - point[2]
        if dx>500.0:
            dx=dx-1000.0
        if dx<-500.0:
            dx=dx+1000.0
        if dy>500.0:
            dy=dy-1000.0
        if dy<-500.0:
            dy=dy+1000.0
        if dz>500.0:
            dz=dz-1000.0
        if dz<-500.0:
            dz=dz+1000.0
        dist = np.sqrt(dx**2 + dy**2 + dz**2)
        inv_dist = -1./dist
        sum_inv_dist = sum_inv_dist+inv_dist
    sum_inv_dist_array.append(sum_inv_dist)
    sum_inv_dist = 0.0
    n = n+1
time2 = time.clock()
print time2-time1
```

This code is slow and take between 5 to 6 minutes to run.
Numpy functions that operate on arrays are fast and a good way to avoid computationally heavy looping.

So, I tried to speed it up by doing the following:

```
time3 = time.clock()
dxx = np.array([[gal[0]-point[0] for gal in gal_pos] for point in sph_rand_pos_u])
dyy = np.array([[gal[1]-point[1] for gal in gal_pos] for point in sph_rand_pos_u])
dzz = np.array([[gal[2]-point[2] for gal in gal_pos] for point in sph_rand_pos_u])
dxx[np.where(dxx>500.0)] -= 1000.0
dxx[np.where(dxx<-500.0)] += 1000.0
dyy[np.where(dyy>500.0)] -= 1000.0
dyy[np.where(dyy<-500.0)] += 1000.0
dzz[np.where(dzz>500.0)] -= 1000.0
dzz[np.where(dzz<-500.0)] += 1000.0
dist_d = np.sqrt(dxx**2 + dyy**2 + dzz**2)
inv_dist_d = -1./dist_d
sum_dist = [np.sum(distance) for distance in inv_dist_d]
time4 = time.clock()
print (time4-time3)/60.0
```

The time this takes is about 1.5 minutes which is good.

Is there any other way to speed up my calculations? More pythonic ways?

Thanks!

Comment: Any particular reason you used `dxx` for all the comparisons in the second version? For example, `dyy[np.where(dxx>500.0)]` instead of `dyy[np.where(dyy>500.0)]`?

Comment: Mad props to for finding the most obvious and annoying mistake!

Comment: Profile! See where your code is spending the most time and focus on that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use broadcast to calculate the different, use `sum(axis=1)` to sum every row:

```
dxx = gal_pos[None, :, 0] - sph_rand_pos_u[:, None, 0]
dyy = gal_pos[None, :, 1] - sph_rand_pos_u[:, None, 1]
dzz = gal_pos[None, :, 2] - sph_rand_pos_u[:, None, 2]

dxx[dxx>500.0] -= 1000.0
dxx[dxx<-500.0] += 1000.0
dyy[dyy>500.0] -= 1000.0
dyy[dyy<-500.0] += 1000.0
dzz[dzz>500.0] -= 1000.0
dzz[dzz<-500.0] += 1000.0
dist_d = np.sqrt(dxx**2 + dyy**2 + dzz**2)
inv_dist_d = -1./dist_d

sum_dist2 = np.sum(inv_dist_d, axis=1)
```

**Edited**: don't need `where`.

Comment: It is possible that calling `where` is adding more overhead than what is saving. Use `dxx[dxx>500.0]` instead and check if it is faster.

Comment: @Davidmh, yes you are right, boolean index is faster.